# Ropsten light node block number ~1000 greater than it should be

Tags: synchronization, ropsten, nodes, block-interval

I'm running geth on Ropsten, using

`geth --ropsten --syncmode "light" --http.addr localhost --http.port 8545 --rpc`

My most recent block number is `10266786` (and increasing), whereas etherscan.io says `10265079` and  others confer something within that range of etherscan. About an hour ago, my block number was also `10266000 < n < 10267000`, though etherscan and others showed somewhere in the range `10264000 < n < 10265000`. I'm fairly new to ethereum. Is somebody sending malicious blocks to light nodes in the Ropsten testnet? Or is there an easy fix to this?

Comment: What's your geth version?

Comment: 1.9.25-stable -- I switched to using Infura now after writing this btw, but figure should still keep the question open in case it's relevant to others

Comment: Berlink fork was applied to Ropsten back in March, and you need at least [geth v1.10.1](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.10.1). Perhaps your node is following a forked branch. That kinda explains the difference. The other explanation is that etherscan testnets sometimes breaks or isn't updated quick enough because it is a testnet.